# How can I make W10 open RTFs with WordPad_XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, rtf, wordpad

I don't like the ribbon interface, but I do like WordPad with RTF (I use it as a convenient, lightweight editor). When I upgraded from XP to W7 I simply overwrote the WordPad directory (`C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`) with the XP files and it worked; that is, double-clicking an RTF file opened the XP WordPad. But with W10 I can't write in that directory.

I tried making `D:\ProgFils\WordPad_XP\wordpad.exe` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\WordPad_XP\wordpad.exe` but neither `ControlPanel>DefaultApps` nor `Settings>System>DefaultApps` worked, and `RightClick>OpenWith` opened the W10 version.

Can I fix this? I can use regedit and GodMode, and am willing to learn new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed it! I had to rename the executable (to `werdpad.exe`) and then I was able to assign it to .rtf files. I placed the relevant files (the `.exe` and three `.wpc` files) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\WerdPad` and it finally worked. It seems that `wordpad` is a reserved name for Microsoft.

Comment: The Application registration under HKCR\Applications\WordPad.exe registry key points to the original file, which is the one shown in the Default Apps or Open with dialog. If you want to use the same name (wordpad.exe) for the older version of the program, the Applications and App Paths registry keys need to be changed. FYI.

Comment: renaming werdpad.exe lasts as long as next sfc is not run, and next automatic repair doesn't take place. Make a mental note to rename it every time you run sfc or a sytem rapair occurs. Default Programs > Set Associations is permanent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Associations`.
2. Scroll down to `.rtf` and select it.
3. Click "Change program...".
4. In the popup, scroll down and click "More Apps", then scroll down and click "Look for another app on this PC".
5. Browse for the executable.